# Why does parsing a value as a double return a different result than parsing it as a decimal then casting to a double?

Tags: c#, double, decimal

Trying to parse the value *-36.845167* from a string:

```
double result;
double.TryParse("-36.845167", out result);
```

*result* is *-36.845167000000004*

```
decimal value;
decimal.TryParse("-36.845167", out value);
double result = (double)value;
```

*result* is *-36.845167*

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `double` has limited precision, while `decimal` stores decimal digits. Read more here: [Difference between decimal, float and double in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-net)

Basically, `decimal` is better at storing *decimal* representation of the number.

**Edit**: answering your original question more explicitly: Both of your results are kinda *incorrect* since *-36.845167* cannot be represented as `double`. Check out the output of this expression:

```
 result.ToString("G20")
```

on both of your results and you will see that both of them are not equal to *-36.845167*: one of them is *-36.845166999999996* and other is *-36.845167000000004*.

So, both of them are *4e-15* off your original number. What you really see in the debugger (or upon outputting to console) is just the rounding during the conversion to string.

Comment: But why can the correct double be created through casting a double instead of directly with the double's TryParse method?

Answer (score 2):

The two doubles bracketing -36.845167 are -36.84516700000000355430529452860355377197265625 and -36.84516699999999644887793692760169506072998046875

They differ from the exact value by 3.55112206307239830493927001953125E-15 and 
3.55430529452860355377197265625E-15 respectively.

The first one is very slightly closer, so it is the correct IEEE 754 round-to-nearest result. I do not know what the standard requires for casting a C# decimal to double, but, assuming you used the same output method in both cases, it may not have done round-to-nearest.